# Problema API PHP sin Framework con Angular

Tags: php, angular, api

Tengo un problema y es lo siguiente, tengo una API bueno se podría decir API estoy haciendo pruebas, estoy comenzando. Pero el problema es el siguiente:
En mi API tengo para consultar una tabla pues desde el navegador todo normal y en la aplicación Postman también, pero en mi aplicación angular no consulta, hago un log y me sale el siguiente error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://arstrikestudio.com/API/usuario.php?api_action=show&api_ukey=asd&api_id=1'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Instale un plugin de chrome para evitar eso y al momento de hacer log me sale undefined y no se si tengo que hacer una configuración en mi hosting o esta algo mal el código.

El servicio Angular LLamado User asi le coloque:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class Usuario{
    public url:string;
    constructor(
        public _http:HttpClient
    ){
this.url="http://arstrikestudio.com/API/usuario.php?";
    }
    getuser():Observable<any>{
        return this._http.get(this.url+'api_action=show&api_ukey=asd&api_id=1');
    }
    getconsul(id){
        return id;
    }
}
```

pero no me manda nada. Si lo colocan en el navegador si muestra los datos.

¿Cual es mi problema me podrían ayudar, que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: Prueba agregando en tu código PHP lo siguiente:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");`

Coloca tambien tu código PHP.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz Lo agregue pero sigue igual, será porque estoy tratando de consumir mi API que tengo en mi hosting desde mi localhost ?

Comment: Claro, pero si lo puedes hacer, justamente estoy consumiendo un api en Angular con un backend hecho en laravel que subi a Heroku.

Comment: Prueba hacerlo de esta forma 
`getData(): Observable<any> {
    let Url = 'yoururl';
    return this.http.get<any>(Url);
  }` Basicamente agregando `<any>` luego del get.